# Finding error information in Developers Console for Google Static Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I received an email from google with a subject like of "Your Google Static Maps API requests are generating warnings, and results may be incomplete" with the following info:

> We noticed that some of your requests to the Google Static Maps API are
>   generating warnings, and the results may be missing markers or polylines.
>   Please visit https://goo.gl/UABlDC to understand how you can identify the
>   warnings you are receiving and also learn about possible rootcauses. We
>   strongly encourage you to take necessary actions to fix them.
>
> Note that after 90 days, we may start displaying a small visual warning on
>   the rendered map to alert you to the presence of these warnings.

This email didn't give me any information as to which application was causing errors, and I know of no errors in any of my applications (doesn't mean there aren't any, I just don't know where). I went through the Developers Console to see if I could find anything, and while the Manage Projects page says I have errors on some of my applications, but I can't seem to find any information on exactly what those errors are.

Where can I see more information on these errors?

Answer (score 1):

From the [link in the quoted email](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/error-messages):

> You can see the warnings in the Chrome DevTools Console, the Firefox Web Console, or other equivalent tools in your browser.
>
> Note: You should check for warnings if you notice that something is missing from the map. It's also a good idea to check for warnings before launching a new application. Consider also whether user input or internationalization could lead to unexpected characters or malformed latitude/longitude coordinate specifications in the request.

[This reference from the Google Maps Javascript API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Troubleshooting) links to the [documentation on debugging in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: The problem is that I don't know on which page the error is happening. I just have that email from google telling me there is an error.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to watch out for the error bar (should you stumble upon it), or reports / comments from your site's users about it.